# how to select data based on the joint results of subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, subquery

I want to select some data from a table A based on the subquery result from another table B

Structure of A

```
Dates         NAME  VALUE
02/01/2012    CC1   CC_value
02/01/2012    CC2   CC_value
02/02/2012    CC1   CC_value
02/02/2012    CC2   CC_value
......
03/01/2012    CC8   CC_value
......
```

Structure of B

```
Dates          CC
02/01/2012     CC1
02/02/2012     CC2
......
03/01/2012     CC7
```

Given Dates range, I want to first find the corresponding pair of (Dates, CC) in Table B and 
based on the pair, I want to find CC_value in Table A.

I am trying to write a pair in ms-access, but it is not allowed. How can I write the sql?
Any idea?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic join query with filtering:

```
select a.value
from a join
     b
     on a.dates = b.dates and a.name = b.cc
where b.date between DATE1 and DATE2
```

I don't think you need a subquery at all.

Comment: @user2460432 . . . I am not aware of any limitation on Access joining on columns that are text.  For instance, nothing in the documentation mentions such a restriction.  Can you explain your comment?